# aggregate the count if fields in a measurement in Influxdb2

Tags: influxdb-2

I have a measurement "m1" in influxdb2 where data is labeled with 4 different labels, lets call the l1 - l5.
All have a float variable (seconds).

I can count per field with the following query:

```
from(bucket: "my bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "m1")
  |> count()
  |> yield(name: "count")
```

i will get raw data with 5 rows, 1 row for each field with the count of the values per field.

How can I sum the 5 values to a single count over all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [ungroup](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/group/#ungroup-data) the data and [sum](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/sum) the values then.

```js
from(bucket: "my bucket")
  |> ...
  |> count()
  |> group()
  |> sum()
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for the late response